# Creating a SVG element with a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I need to learn how to create a SVG element with a javascript function

The style of my html file essentially:

```
     <body>
     <svg></svg>
     <script></script>
     </body>
```

My script contains a function that creates a chart, if the function was hypothetically called create(chartName, chartAxises) how would I create a chart inside my svg element?

Thank you in advance, and I apologize for my unorganized thoughts. I just need to know the syntax, I have tried multiple things for hours so now I'm hoping for a different perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than reinvent the wheel, what you could do is, use some svg libraries to populate your graph based on the data and attributes. 
https://d3js.org/

Comment: Totally agree, d3 is a powerful tool for your said requirements.

Comment: What's the error are you getting ?

Comment: It doesn't run, for example if I take the code from this websitse:

http://bl.ocks.org/weiglemc/6185069

I get a blank webpage :(

I get two errors, XMLHttpRequest cannot load  and ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Seems data is undefined. . Your data has to have some values. Check and see why it's unable to read the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {